# Find the common path among all possible paths in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, static-analysis, control-flow-graph

I'm trying to find the common nodes that are always visited by each and every possible path in a cyclic directed graph. My idea would be to compute all possible paths and then search for the common elements. However, **a)** that does not seem to be very efficient and **b)** it does not account for cycles.

The **goal**: is to implement [oblivious hashing perimeter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/chen02oh.pdf) as a tamper-resistance method. For that I need to identify a set of common basic blocks that are input agnostic in a control flow graph. Put another way, I want to find deterministic chunks of a program (set of basic blocks) that will be executed for any given input.

Comment: `I'm trying to find the common nodes that are always visited by **each and every possible path** in a cyclic directed graph` That's a problematic statement. An empty path (length 0, from a node to itself) is also a path, and according to this, no node (maybe except a graph with |V|<=1) has any node that meets that condition. You need to refine the "each and every path" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you need to provide a set of start vertices and end vertices for the paths. So your statement would be:

> Find all vertices that are always passed when traversing from any vertex in set S to any vertex in set E.

Then you will notice that the vertices you are searching for are Vertex Separators. Algorithms exist to compute a minimum vertex separator.